# open modal inside jquery function save changes and continue back to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am new to jQuery and bootstrap. 
I have a jQuery function which is triggered from another click event, then i am opening the modal and the modal has a few input fields and once they are saved, I want to continue back to the jQuery function which initiated the show modal.

Also, when I save the data from the modal it's calling another function to save the values.
Is there something like "wait till the modal is closed".

Code piece (sharing the pseudo code)

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
          //opening the modal here...
          $('#myModal').modal('show');


          if (title) {
            console.log(title)
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end,
                allDay: allDay
              },
              true // make the event "stick"
            );
          }
          calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        }


//modal code , closing it once data is fetched..
$('#testData').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        startTime= $('#startTime').val();
        endTime=$('#endTime').val();
        title=$('titleH').val();
        console.log(startTime);
        console.log(endTime);
        $('#myModal').modal('close');
      });
```

Once the modal is closed, how do i go back to the previous function callback?

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events ```$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})```

Comment: No.  A modal doesn't stop execution of javascript (like an alert/confirm) so the rest of the code runs before the modal is even displayed.  This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for the link. So the only solutions is promises ?

Comment: @clav i am using bootstrap 4

Comment: @mischa thanks for info, the problem is i have already invoked the function to open the modal. and one the form inside the modal is saved i am closing the modal but i want to return to the callback where i had opened the modal

Answer (score 0):

You can't really return to the function that showed the modal after it's shown. What you can do is tie an event handler to the modal's close event that calls a function containing the logic you want to execute after the modal is closed.  If I'm understanding your code correctly, I think you want to execute the following logic after the modal closes:

```
if (title) {
  console.log(title)
  calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
    title: title,
    start: start,
    end: end,
    allDay: allDay
  },
  true // make the event "stick"
  );
}
calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
```

Is that correct?  If so, something like this should work:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  if (title) {
    console.log(title)
    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
      title: title,
      start: start,
      end: end,
      allDay: allDay
    },
    true // make the event "stick"
    );
  }
  calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
});
```

Comment: i got your point. the function is quite big i just pasted a piece from it.
i will try it thanks for the suggestion. Another alternative is using promise